# Where to find buttons eagle cad

Tags: schematics, eaglecad, cad

Does any one know where to find buttons in EAGLE that look something like the one in this schematic?

[image: style 1]

I'm making a schematic and all I can find are complex looking buttons. If those are not available, then can someone help me find a normal switch, like this:

[image: style 2]

I can't seem to find this in the EAGLE libraries, either.

Comment: It is not hard to draw your own symbols and build your own components in EAGLE. [I have a series of training videos on this on my site](http://tangentsoft.net/elec/movies/). Also, beware that the two symbols you give in your post mean different things. The first symbol is most often used with momentary pushbuttons, while the second implies some kind of latching switch, such as a toggle.

Comment: Have you tried Eagle support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best answer is to make your own, it's easy.  Someone else's library parts aren't going to adhere to your conventions for the silkscreen, hole sizes, BOM handling, etc, etc.  I never even look in the Eagle libraries as they are basically useless.

In your case, you haven't even said what kind of button, only shown the schematic symbol.  There are many many many different "buttons" from various manufacturers.  Most of these will require a different footprint.  You have to specify a particular part before you can even tell if someone else's Eagle button is applicable to your case.

In the off chance you can live with *my* conventions, download my Eagle Tools release from http://www.embedinc.com/pic/dload.htm and look around in the "Switch" library.  There are some buttons in there, but again, there is no way to know what you actually want.

Comment: I am not too concerned about detailed button specifications because I am not creating a PCB.All I want to do is create a schematic for my microcontroller circuit, print it out and use it to guide me when I'm physically building the circuit on a breadboard in the lab, when I'm in the lab I'll probably just grab whatever buttons/switches they have lying around and use them in my circuit.The problem I was having is that I couldn't seem to find a normal looking button, but I ended up finding one called "31-XX" in the switch-omiron library.

Comment: @Killa: I don't understand.  You already have normal looking buttons in the schematic you show in the question.

Comment: @KillaKem: EAGLE's schematic editor isn't particularly well suited to drawing schematics only. Its main job is to communicate a circuit design to the PCB layout tool, since it wants to tie physical packages to each symbol you drop on the schematic sheet. The [ExpressPCB](http://expresspcb.com/ExpressPCBHtm/Download.htm) and [KiCad](https://kicad.org) schematic editors are better for this. But my personal favorite free tool for *just* schematic drawing is [gschem](http://www.geda-project.org/). You might also like [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/), given your breadboard target. [Edited by a mod]

Comment: @Warren: That's the first I've heard that Eagle isn't well suited to drawing good schematics. Just like with any tool, it's possible to make a mess, and doing it right requires neatness and attention to detail. I've done dozens of schematics professionally with Eagle, which included sending them to customers. I've never had a complaint about them being difficult to read, and a few have even commented they liked my schematics. Eagle is perfectly capable of good schematics.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I'm not saying it can't be done. I'm saying that if the end product is the schematic only, there are better free tools. If you don't care about a PCB, you shouldn't have to choose SO-8 vs DIP-8 on every op-amp symbol, or uA741 vs TL072, or... A tool without a hard tie between the schematic and PCB will let you drop a generic op-amp symbol on the schematic and leave it at that. As for "why gschem", it's that I think its schematics look nicer than EAGLE's. No ugly line through the diode symbol, sharp vector output, etc.

Comment: @Warren: You apparently don't know Eagle very well.  If you just want to draw a schematic, you can chose any part that has a symbol you like.  I do this routinely when posting schematics here, for example.  As for ugly line thru a diode symbol, I have no idea what you are talking about.  In any case, how the symbol looks is up to you.  This is not a function of Eagle.  I've posted losts of schematics here, all of them drawn with Eagle.  None of the diodes had ugly lines, whatever that means anyway.  Don't ding the tool just because you don't know it well.

Comment: *This* ugly line: http://tangentsoft.net/elec/misc/ugly-eagle-diode.png It's purely due to the fact that EAGLE's default grid and pin lengths conspire to force the C and A pins together in the middle of the triangle. The triangle [should be empty or solid black](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Electronic_symbols). Yes, I realize I can draw my own diode symbols, but I don't have to when I use `gschem`: its diode symbol is already correct. As for my expertise, I've racked up ~1000 hours over 10 years with EAGLE. Expert? No. Newbie? Also no.

Comment: @Olin : I got the pictures in the post from google, I didn't create them myself.

Comment: @Warren: That's a stupidly drawn symbol and isn't inherent to Eagle at all. See any of the many schematics I have posted here with diodes in them. It's OK to prefer a different package, and I'm not saying anything bad about the others, but it's unfair to complain about a package when it isn't used properly. Suggest the others if you like, I'm not objecting to that, but don't tell them not to use Eagle because you don't use it properly. You can make a mess with any tool, but that's not the tool's fault. Proper symbols *are* available in Eagle.

Comment: "...isn't inherent to Eagle..." Okay, try this. Say `File > New Schematic`. Say `ADD`. In the search box, say `diode`. Scroll through the result set with the down arrow key while looking at the symbols. They're nearly *all* "stupidly drawn." I didn't get to a correct diode symbol in my freshly installed copy of EAGLE 5.11 (no custom libraries) until I got about 90% through the search results, in the `semicon-smd-ipc` library, with the `D-FILL-` part. I see the same thing in a freeware install of 6.4.0 on a different machine. Defaults matter.

Comment: "Attackers on www.embedinc.com might attempt to trick you into installing programs that harm your browsing experience (for example, by changing your homepage or showing extra ads on sites you visit). Google Safe Browsing recently found harmful programs on www.embedinc.com."

Comment: @Nul: Yes, Google uses rather primitive virus scanners and doesn't care.  There is nothing unsafe on our web site.  Google gets false positives, but try telling them that. *We don't care, we don't have to, we're Google"*.  Try using a better browser, like IE.

Answer (score -1):

You can find simple buttons under the switch-omron folder.